# responsive grid 2 colum in a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this static markup which make my layout flex and 2 column nicely.

```
<Row>
  <Col span={6}>content</Col>
  <Col span={6}>content</Col>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Col span={6}>content</Col>
  <Col span={6}>content</Col>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Col span={6}>content</Col>
  <Col span={6}>content</Col>
</Row>
```

But I have to convert it to a dynamic list since it has to render data from the backend.

Doing this won't work

```
 {ads && ads.map((obj, index) => (
  <Row>
    <Col span={6}>{obj.content}</Col>
  </Row>
  )
)}
```

because it will print each row for each iteration. I thought of using %, but I forgot how I did it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop (not sure that thats the best way... new to JavaScript):

```
{ads && for(var i = 0; i < ads.length; i += 2) {
  <Row>
    <Col span={6}>{ads[i]}</Col>
    <Col span={6}>{ads[i+1]</Col>
  </Row>
}
```

You would have to figure out how to deal with `ads.lenght`not being divisible by two, though.